# Access Denied - user does not have permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, access-denied

I have an employee that left the company and has now returned. I recreated her e-mail address the same as it was before, but when I send her the link to share the site she gets an error message that she does not have permission to access the site.

I have checked her permission levels and they are all accurate. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which SharePoint version do you use? And which kind of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If you works in SharePoint server, try to follow the steps below to remove the user and re-add the user in SharePoint:

1. Go to User Information list( http://spsite/_layouts/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0)  to delete this user.
2. Remove the user from SharePoint (Site Settings->People & Groups).
3. Run IISRESET on the web server, then the SQL Server.
4. Add the user to SharePoint. Assigned the correct permissions for SharePoint.

If you use SharePoint Online, remove the user account in the User Information List firstly, then re-invite the user.

Reference:  [How to remove deleted users from SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/remove-users)

Answer (score 0):

If you had previously given the user permissions under the "old" account, and need the user to be able to access the same sites with their "new" account, you need to run the [`move-spuser` PowerShell cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser) to tell SharePoint that those two accounts belong to the same user.